# how to pass information from one class to another

Tags: c#, c++, oop, interface

I am using a function which will take states of both classes how should I generate that function, right now i'm doing it like this

```
 if((b1.fxmin>s.xmin&&s.ymin==b1.fymax)&&b1.fxmin<s.xmax&&s.ymin==b1.fymax))
  { 
    collides=true;
    b1.isFiring=false;
  }
Else if((b1.fxmin>s1.xmin&&s1.ymin==b1.fymax)&&b1.fxmin<s1.xmax&&s1.ymin==b1.fymax))
 {
   collides1=true;
   b1.isFiring=false;
 }
```

> In this project a bullet will hit a spider and if its collides then spider will vanish, **b1** is the object of class bullet and **s1** and **s** are spiders.
>
> I have seven spiders in this game and I have created 7 collides variable and seven if statements this means that when ever i increase a spider i need to add this collide variable and if statement

I tried to do this in bullet class but couldn't succeed. how should i pass spider object to bullet class?

Comment: I am doing all this in main function of class Program

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you want a non-member function that takes one bullet and one spider as arguments, then you should edit the title; it is inaccurate. Could you give us more information about what you want this function to do, and the criteria for collision?

Comment: thank you for your advice, 

>whenever a bullet is fired it will check if it coincides with a spider, this function is called when bullet is fired, b1.isFiring=true, these if statements are checking whether bullets collide or not, if it collides then bullet firing state will set to false and **collides** (a loacal variable) will set to true and if **collides** is true then it will remove spider from screen

Comment: This doesn't answer your question (I think benjy does a good job) but I would suggest declaring your bullets and spiders as arrays rather than individual variables. That'll save you a lot of repeat code. Then you can just itterate: `foreach (b in bullets)` `b.collides(s)`

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a Spider to the bullet class as follows:

```
// Bullet.h
class Spider;

class Bullet {
  ...
  bool isColliding(const Spider &s);
}

// Bullet.cpp
#include "Spider.h" // or whatever header you're using.
...
bool Bullet::isColliding(const Spider &s) {
  // Collision logic
}
```

You can then call this function from you main by doing:

```
if(b1.isColliding(s1)) {
  // Do something.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of ways to do that.. First you have to be specific that the variables that are you comparing from two different classes are private or public variables?

If they are public variables, then pass the address objects to the function as an input arguments...like this function(class1* ptr1, class2* ptr2)...and access those variables using -> inside the function..

But if you are using those variables as a private members to the respective classes, there is one good way to do this..that is called friend classes..you make one class friend to the other..and then you can use that function which has to be member of one class access the variables of the other class even if they are private..google friend classes for more info.